# how to read a linux etc/passwd file and compare the user input name for authentication in C

Tags: c

This is the program i have written can anyone tell what is wrong with it, because whatever input i give, it shows valid user.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#define max_size 20
void main()
{
 File *Fptr;
 char username[max_size];
 char line[20];
 if((fptr=fopen("/etc/passwd","r"))==NULL)
 { 
   printf("cannot open file");
 }
 else
  {
      fptr=fopen("/etc/passwd","r");
      fputs("enter the username",stdout);
      fflush(stdout);
      fgets(username,sizeof username,stdin);
      while((fgets(line,sizeof(line),fptr))!=NULL)
      { 
          if(strcmp(line,username))
          {
             printf("%s valid user",username);
             break; 
          }
          else
            {
              printf("%s not valid user",username);
            }    
      } 
   fclose(fptr);
  }
}
```

Comment: FYI, in the future, select your code and click the `101010` button to format it properly.

Comment: thanks i'll take care of it in future

Answer (score 6):

Could you use `getpwent` for this task?

see: [getpwent(3)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/getpwent.3.html) and [opengroup's getpwent](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/getpwent.html)

- [Here's a generic example of usage](http://www.chemie.fu-berlin.de/chemnet/use/info/libc/libc_25.html#SEC452), and
- [here's another - how to look up users](http://www.chemie.fu-berlin.de/chemnet/use/info/libc/libc_25.html#SEC445).

and

- [here's the **Stackoverflow discussion** on the topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1610203/unix-programming-not-sure-how-to-use-the-passwd-struct)

Regards

rbo

Answer (score 3):

`strcmp` is a three-way comparator. It tells you if the strings are equal or if the first string is lexicographically less or greater than second.

Because of this, its results are a bit unintuitive when used as booelan values. It returns `0` when the strings match, which evaluates to false in an `if` statement. It returns nonzero values, usually -1 or 1, (all of which evaluate to true) when the strings are different.

If you want to test if two strings are the same, you should change

```
if(strcmp(line,username))
```

to

```
if(strcmp(line,username) == 0)
```

Also take note of Starkey's answer about the extra contents of lines in `/etc/passwd`. If you make only the change above, your program will always return "not a valid user".

Comment: if i put the condition as you said it shows me the "else" part i.e. not valid what should i do

Comment: Like I said, that change is necessary but not sufficient to make your program work. You have to separate the username from the other information on the line that you read from /etc/passwd. If you're trying to learn how to parse text, look into `strtok`, but if you're just trying to get something done, you should instead use the POSIX APIs for getting information out of /etc/passwd, which rubber boots linked to.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of trying to parse `/etc/passwd` manually, you might want to use [`getpwnam`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/getpwnam.3.html) instead.

Answer (score 2):

`strcmp` returns 0 (which is false) if the two strings are exactly equivalent, or a non-zero number (which is true) if the strings differ at all.

So firstly, you appear to have your if-test the wrong way around. Secondly, you need to test just the leading `n` characters, where `n` is the length of the username. Off the top of my head, I suggest you try replacing your if-test with:

```
if (!strncmp(line, username, strlen(username))
```

Answer (score 1):

`strcmp` compares the whole line in the passwd file with what you have entered. The passwd file contains more than just the user name on each line (look at a passwd file to see what I'm talking about).

Comment: i saw the file passwd file what is way i should compare the string

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the fact that your `strcmp` test condition is wrong as others have already pointed out, lines in the passwd file contain more than just the username. You could use `strstr` to see if the name is present in a particular line.

```
if(strstr(line, username) == line)
{
    /* valid user */
}
```