# how to compare user given input(string) to /etc/passwd file in ubuntu in c

Tags: c

I want to compare user given input i.e a username to the already stored usernames in /etc/passwd file in ubuntu. I am trying it in C. any help please

Comment: If you've made an attempt, can you post what you have so far? It's not really clear what your goal is.

Comment: i want to write a program to validate user in ubuntu ....input is user given and it is compared to /etc/passwd file

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3567809/how-to-read-a-linux-etc-passwd-file-and-compare-the-user-input-name-for-authentic

Comment: is this an assignment? seen the coincidence that the same question was asked yesterday do you follow the same course?

Answer (score 4):

```
#include <pwd.h>
...

struct passwd *e = getpwnam(userName);
if(e == NULL) {
   //user not found
} else {
  //found the user
}
```

See docs [here](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/getpwnam.html) and [here](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/basedefs/pwd.h.html)

(If you actually want to authenticate the user as well, there's more work needed though )

Answer (score 0):

This code prints all the usernames from /etc/passwd.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{  
        char buffer[128];
        char* username;
        FILE* passwdFile;

        passwdFile = fopen("/etc/passwd", "r");
        while (fgets(buffer, 128, passwdFile) != NULL)
        {
                username = strtok(buffer, ":");
                printf("username: %s\n", username);
        }
        fclose(passwdFile);
        return 0;
}
```

Modify to compare `username` to your input.

Comment: Much better to use the getpwnam() function that is designed to find the given user name in the password database, which might not always be (just) the /etc/passwd file.